# Grunt concat specific file first, then all remaining files

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-concat

I'm relatively new to grunt and I'm working to concat my files. I've been digging and haven't been able to come up with a good answer for this:

```
concat({
    src : ['file1.js', ...all other files... ],
    dest : 'dist/build.js'
});
```

Where `file1.js` is always added first, then it pulls in all remaining files. I *could* do it all by hand, but in the spirit of automation I was hoping to find a more dynamic method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

src is just a simple array which you can of course fill dynamically. e.g. you can read the files manually, sort them by whatever you want, and add that array to your config!